Is it okay to ask your undergraduate final project supervisor for a letter of recommendation for Phd admissions?
She will be my third referee. First one is my Master's thesis supervisor and the second was my masters co-supervisor, both phds. The person in question has just recently undergone her phd proposal defense so I was wondering if she will be a good nominee for my letter of recommendation? Had a very good experience with her and my bachelor's project was also one of the top 3 best projects.
P.S: My field is Electrical Engineering.

You must have had a professor who you did your project under. Generally this will be the PhD advisor of this candidate. Ask the professor (politely ofcourse) to coordinate with this student to write you a letter. That's generally how it happens.
